# Google search module for node.js not working?

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-search

I am trying to use the following node module https://github.com/jprichardson/node-google in a web app I am building. The ReadMe file says to use it as follows. However res.links is an empty list for me. I am using it exactly as the example shows. Is the module broken or is it just not working for me?

```
/*This prints out the first 50 search results of the query `node.js best practices`. */

var google = require('google')

google.resultsPerPage = 25
var nextCounter = 0

google('node.js best practices', function (err, res){
  if (err) console.error(err)

  for (var i = 0; i < res.links.length; ++i) {
    var link = res.links[i];
    console.log(link.title + ' - ' + link.href)
    console.log(link.description + "\n")
  }

  if (nextCounter < 4) {
    nextCounter += 1
    if (res.next) res.next()
  }
})
```

I expect res.links to show an array of links. However it returns the empty list.

Comment: Looks like it's not an official search tool.  Could be that google have managed to block this tool.